# C: merging temp files created with tmpfile() function with multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, merge, pthreads

I have n files and my program needs to merge the contents of all into an one file using threads and temp files (have to use tmpfile()). When creating a thread it has to merge 2 files into a temp file (temp1) then another thread will merge the next 2 files into another temp file (temp2) and so on, then in the next level another thread should merge temp1 with temp2 into another temp file.

[image]

I was thinking in creating an array of file names passing it to pthread_create as argument, and the function should return the array modified too but i can't figure how to get the tempfile name. Will be something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int n = argc -1;

char *files_arr[n];

pthread_t threads[n-1];

}

    for (int i=0; i < argc; i++)

    {
       pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, temp_merge, (void *) &files_arr);
    }
}//end main

void *temp_merge (void *arg){

    char *myarray[];
    myarray = (char *) arg;
    FILE *f1, *f2, *tf;
    tf = tmpfile();

    //code to merge f1 and f2 into tf, f1 and f2 could be temp files created before

     pthread_exit((void*) myarray); //Do I lose the temp file using pthread_exit? 
}
```

The question is: How can I access to a temp file openned before with tmp() in a previous thread to generate new temporary files?

Comment: "i can't figure how to get the tempfile name." - you can't, in general That's the point of tmpfile

Comment: That's right Paul, so how do I "store" these temp files to read them later?

Comment: create an array of saved names. after each step, merge those files into the new files (saving those names as you go).  the word 'recursive' comes to mind here ;)

Comment: if you mean by "later" another run of this or another program: you cannot, because tmpfile() deletes the file after completion;

Comment: @Kevin the problem is i can't "save" the names of the temp files using tmpfile() and i thought in recursion but i think if i use it its gonna do all in one thread (i need a thread for each merging). @Peter when i say "later" i mean in a next thread at the same program

Comment: @g0d1anier: I'm just curious, is there a reason you want to use multithreading for this? It seems to me that your program will be completely I/O bound so you're adding a lot of complexity for little benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `tmpnam()` instead of `tmpfile()`, and manually open/close/delete files as necessary?

Comment: Or we could use a global array of FILE * ptrs to tmp files, and pass in the pair of indexes which are needed by the thread merging the two temp files.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Well as global array i don't know the array size yet but i could use a malloc, then you say i can get access to the files content throw pointers? could be. @Oli i was doing a research about tmpnam() and i have the problem of how to get the temp file name.

Comment: @g0d1anier: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam/.  This is C++ reference, but it's basically the same idea.

Comment: from the OP - "have to use tmpfile()"

Answer (score 0):

You have the list of files to begin with (I assume), so you'll open all of them (returning `FILE *`).

In your mergesort function (MSF), tmpfile() returns a `FILE *` which is what your MSF should return.  So, your return value from the MSF becomes one of the two inputs your next invocation of MSF.  This continues until you have only one `FILE *` to act upon.